# Triggering Multitail to start tailing when 'string' arrives

Tags: multitail

I am using multitail to monitor a group of logs.
I have been seeking a solution in the multitail options to start tailing a log only after the arrival of a matched string. I see plenty of capability in multitail to use -e and/or -ev to include/exclude rows that match the regex criteria, but not so much using a "trigger" to start tailing.

I am currently targeting 4-6 logs, separate panes, not merged, where the criteria above would be applied to each log entry ( -i ).

I would appreciate thoughts on an approach.

Comment: maybe "program | sed '1,/trigger/d' " ? multitee is a fine program but sometimes just go back to basics.

Comment: @icarus  I completely understand and would agree if this were starting from nothing, but this is an established environment and was looking to tweak the existing scripting. The 4-6 logs is just a test set, but other existing collections follow. There was the thought of using the `-j` option of taking from stdin, so maybe it could be a combination of what I have with what you suggest with sed .  Thanks for the input.